# How to trigger a function by looking at time in database table

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I have rails 4 application and I want to trigger a rake task by looking at a time column in the database table.

The rake task should get triggered when `Time.now` equals the time stored in the column of the table.

How can I best approach this problem and solve it elegantly?

My database is PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot have an event triggered automatically by the database when a specific date/time is reached.

In order to do what you want, you would have to run a task that would query the database each second (or minute, or whatever -- depending on the granularity you need) and compare the current time with the database column which contains the date you're interested in.

Comment: So basically I need to have a cron job continuously running and checking database table and trigger the rake task. Correct?

Comment: Yes, but you may want to also consider any performance implications of doing so.